# How can I get the jobs count when I started a spark application

Tags: apache-spark, jobs

I was trying to get the jobs count in **the first time**,
and I try to get it from JobprogressListener. But only stages and tasks information, not jobs. We know Spark application generate the jobs "as it goes".

But if there is a component or a class recording the job information UP FRONT?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but I would recommend Spark RESTful API

Steps:

1. Get `applicationId` from `SparkContext.applicationId` property
2. Query `http://context-url:port/applications/api/v1/[app-id]/jobs` Where context-url is address of your Spark Driver and port is port with Web UI, it's 4040 normally. [Here is documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api)
3. Count jobs that are returned in response from RESTful API